# A reincarnation manhua in which the main character is a pervert wizard (magician) who reincarnated after dying

Tags: story-identification, magic, manga, reincarnation

The main character (MC) is a perverted sage/wizard/magician, who once was part of the hero's party.

After living a long life and inventing lot of artifacts, he wasn't able to surpass death. When he was on brink of death, he succeeded in inventing a reincarnation spell and died by being slapped by his disciple for sexual harassment.

After he succeeded in reincarnating into a noble family specializing in magic, the MC was abandoned in a forest by his parents, because the device for measuring mana (which he himself invented) was unable to measure his vast amount of mana and showed that he had very little mana.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. I had to make some guesses as to what you meant while editing this, changing certain words in the process. Feel free to edit the question yourself if I got anything wrong, or for any other reason.

Comment: By the way, I know you said this is a manhua, but can you confirm whether this was in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: mostly black & white

Comment: I know I've read this, and I swear it's even been asked on this site before, but now I can't find it. Do you remember any other details of this story? How did he survive being in the forest? Did he get adopted by a new family? Or wolves? Monsters? Or just live on his own? Was there an overarching plot you can remember, like some evil organization trying to destroy the world? Or was it more laid back?

Comment: Actually i only got to read it's first chapter after that i couldn't find anything else about it...

Answer (score 2):

When you provided the little detail of the MC being perverted and dying due to a slap from his disciple then I immediately knew what was the Manhua due to the fact that I had it bookmarked.

Manhua: [Since My Previous Life Was A Wise Man, I Can Afford To Live](https://www.mreader.co/manga/since-my-previous-life-was-a-wise-man-i-can-afford-to-live/)

> Born to excellent parents, Reus is abandoned shortly after being born due to a mismeasurement of magical aptitude. However, he was a
> super baby who had the memory and ability of his previous life where
> he was touted as a Great Sage, and was able to fly, not to mention
> conversation and walking! Adventuring with the sacred dragon familiar,
> Lindworm (super strong), enjoy the life of a baby Sage who becomes a
> person and enjoys freedom!